# html2canvas - how to define top, left, bottom, right to have auto crop?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2canvas

I have a page 1280x768. following code is making 1280x768 full page snapshot, but i need to ignore from top 10px, from left 10px from bottom 10px, from right 10px.

Can you do that crop/scale or so before or after `document.body.appendChild(canvas);` ? using CSS3 or JS or so?

```
window.takeScreenShot = function() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("top"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        },
        width:1280,
        height:768
    });
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use an offscreen canvas, on which you will draw your rendered canvas with the desired offset.

Here is a quickly written function which may not fulfill all requirements, but which can at least give you an idea : 
 note that it uses [latest html2canvas version (0.5.0-beta4)](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases), which now returns a Promise.

```js
function screenshot(element, options = {}) {
  // our cropping context
  let cropper = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  // save the passed width and height
  let finalWidth = options.width || window.innerWidth;
  let finalHeight = options.height || window.innerHeight;
  // update the options value so we can pass it to h2c
  if (options.x) {
    options.width = finalWidth + options.x;
  }
  if (options.y) {
    options.height = finalHeight + options.y;
  }
  // chain h2c Promise
  return html2canvas(element, options).then(c => {
    // do our cropping
    cropper.canvas.width = finalWidth;
    cropper.canvas.height = finalHeight;
    cropper.drawImage(c, -(+options.x || 0), -(+options.y || 0));
    // return our canvas
    return cropper.canvas;
  });
}
```

And call it like that

```
screenshot(yourElement, {
  x: 20, // this are our custom x y properties
  y: 20, 
  width: 150, // final width and height
  height: 150,
  useCORS: true // you can still pass default html2canvas options
}).then(canvas => {
  //do whatever with the canvas
})
```

Since stacksnippets® uses some strong security on their frames, we can't make a live demo in here, but you can find one in this **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/an255nzg/)**.

Oh and for those who want an ES5 version supporting the old html2canvas version, you just have to wrap the cropping function in the onrendered callback, or here is [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ny7qyrqL/) for the lazy ones.